# mysql query issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a small issue:

I recieve few paramaters via ajax and make a sql query. Simple, but this query has some special characters(brazilian) and my query looks like that(as I've made a echo):

```
SELECT neigh 
FROM address_bd 
WHERE 
  state ="AL" 
  AND city ="Maceió" 
GROUP BY neigh 
ORDER BY neigh ASC
```

and in the script is:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT neigh 
  FROM address_bd 
  WHERE state =\"$state\" 
    AND city =\"$city\" 
  GROUP BY neigh 
  ORDER BY neigh ASC
  ";
```

Running it in phpmyadmin return the correct result, but in the script gives 0 results.
My sql row has utf8_general_ci. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

AND here comes the response:

SET character_set_client = utf8;

This resolved the issue. Thank you all and especialy to Inca for sending the link. Thank you again

Comment: Have you tried to see what query has been composed finally?

Comment: You should also define the character set for the connection `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);`

Comment: the first one I showed you. I made a echo of the $sql variable and saw that

Comment: Most probably $city in your script doesn't contain a utf-8 encoded string, do `$city = utf8_encode($city);` does that help?

Comment: Have you tried all the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346531/utf8-problem-with-mysql-5 ? (Make sure your page and connection are also utf8.) Also: utf8_general_ci is a collation option (that has to do with ordering, not with encoding). And depending on where you set `$state` and `$city` your code is likely vulnerable to sql-injection. Consider using prepared statements instead.

Comment: and mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection) not working too. The thing is that"Maceió"  is a result of a previous query, one made with the where state = "AL". Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have `mysql_set_charset(charset);` or corresponding operator for your database driver placed right after your database connect operator.

and `charset` should represent actual charset of your HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT neigh FROM address_bd WHERE state = '$state' AND city = '$city' GROUP BY neigh ORDER BY neigh ASC";
```

If it still does not work add this after mysql_query function

```
print mysql_error();
```

and tell here the error message content.